# Webpack+ tsconfig + dynamic import throwing NoEmit error for .d.ts files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ts-loader

I'm having a strange issue understanding how webpack, tsconfig and .d.ts files are working together.

I've the following project structure:

[image]

The ScriptsApp contains an @types folder as follows:

[image]

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "scripthost",
      "es2018",
      "es2018.promise"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./.out/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "ScriptsApp/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["./ScriptsApp/**/*.tsx", "./ScriptsApp/**/*.ts", "ScriptsApp/@types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "files": ["ScriptsApp/indexApp.tsx"]
}
```

And this is my webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.[hash].js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, ".out/"),
    chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js",
    publicPath: "/",
    hotUpdateChunkFilename: ".hot/hot-update.js",
    hotUpdateMainFilename: ".hot/hot-update.json"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: "manifest"
    },
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          priority: -20,
          chunks: "all"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: ".out/",
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: path.join(__dirname, "./index.html")
    }),

    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      checkSyntacticErrors: true,
      tslint: "./tslint.json",
      tslintAutoFix: true,
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
      async: false,
      reportFiles: ["ScriptsApp/**/*"]
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|ico)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: ".img/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
          publicPath: "/"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: ".fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]",
          publicPath: "/"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        use:"ts-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".scss", ".css", ".png", ".ico", ".json"]
  },
  devtool: "source-map"
};
```

Now my question:
I'm trying to use dynamic imports in one of my React components as follows:

```
private loadComponentFromPath(path: string) {
    import(`../../ScriptsApp/${path}`).then(component =>
      this.setState({
        component: component.default
      })
    );
}
```

As soon as I added dynamic import, my build started showing this error for **all the .d.ts files inside ScriptsApp/@types** folder

```
WARNING in ./ScriptsApp/@types/react-adal.d.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for C:\code\AzureCXP-Eng\src\Applications\AzureCxpWebSite\WebSite\FeedbackSrc\App\ScriptsApp\@types\react-adal.d.ts.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (C:\code\AzureCXP-Eng\src\Applications\AzureCxpWebSite\WebSite\FeedbackSrc\App\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:78:15)
    at successLoader (C:\code\AzureCXP-Eng\src\Applications\AzureCxpWebSite\WebSite\FeedbackSrc\App\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:68:9)
    at Object.loader (C:\code\AzureCXP-Eng\src\Applications\AzureCxpWebSite\WebSite\FeedbackSrc\App\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:22:12)
 @ ./ScriptsApp lazy ^\.\/.*$ namespace object ./@types/react-adal.d.ts
 @ ./ScriptsApp/Routes/AppRoutesList.tsx
 @ ./ScriptsApp/Routes/Routes.tsx
 @ ./ScriptsApp/Components/App.tsx
 @ ./ScriptsApp/indexApp.tsx
 @ ./ScriptsApp/index.tsx
 @ multi webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true ./ScriptsApp/index.tsx
```

How I can currently make the error go away?

1. Move @types folder outside the ScriptsApp, or
2. Not use dynamic imports
3. Rename all .d.ts files under ScriptsApp/@types to .interface.ts --> most baffling to me

I'm not able to understand why though. I'm also new to the entire technology stack so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Please explain this behavior. Also, any suggestions on improving the configs are also much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From another GitHub issue you can do this in your `tsconfig.json` file.

`{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dev_server.js"
]
}`

Could you try to add the line `"noEmit": false.`

Comment: This was the first thing I tried after reading a github issue, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The following code in `tsconfig.json` should ensure that the errors from within `node_modules` will not be reported.

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
     skipLibCheck: true
  }
}
```